# How to prove the inequality?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Given $0<x<1$, $0<a<b<1$, and $a+b<1$, how to prove $a^x(1-ax)<b^x(1-bx)$?

I've tried using $f(x)=x^t(1-xt)$ to do some manipulations (including derivations), but failed.

Comment: Your idea is a good one. If you have tried differentiating $f(x)$, edit your post to include what you got so we can see where you are having trouble.

Comment: Alex-- Just wondering if you read my answer below... If you did and have questions, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x^k(1-kx)=x^k-kx^{k+1}$ has derivative
$$f'(x)=kx^{k-1}(1-(k+1)x).$$
So the only critical point of $f$ is at $1/(k+1)$, and the latter is greater than $1/2$.
Now assume $0<x<y$ and $x+y<1$, and form the difference
$$w(x,y)=f(y)-f(x).$$
We wish to show this is nonnegative under the conditions. The inequalities defining the restriction may be made inclusive, and then the region $R$ satisfying  them is bounded by a triangle with vertices $(0,0),\ (1/2,1/2),\ (0,1).$  When the partials of $w$ are each put to $0$ to get a possible critical point, the only one having positive $x,y$ in the containing square $[0,1]^2$ is $(1/(k+1),1/(k+1))$  but this lies outside $R$ since $1/(k+1)>1/2.$ [We do not even have both partials defined on the left vertical side of $R$, since in fact as $x \to 0^+$ we have $f' \to + \infty.$] Therefore the minimum of $w$ must occur on one of the three edges of the triangle $R$.

On the left edge, where $x=0,\ 0 \le y \le 1$ we have $w=f(y) \ge 0.$ On the edge corresponding to $y=x$ we have $w=0.$ The remaining "downwardly slanted" edge may be parametrized by $(x,y)=(t,1-t)$ where $0 \le t \le 1/2.$ We thus turn to considering the function $h(t)=f(1-t)-f(t).$ The direct derivative of $h$ is involved, and I could not get its zeros. However we only need to show that $h'(t)<0$ for $0 \le t \le 1/2,$ for given that, since at $t=1/2$ we have $h(t)=0,$ we could conclude as desired that $h(t)\ge 0$, i.e. that $w \ge 0$ on the last edge.
Now we take the derivative of $h(t)$ (the chain rule introduces two extra minus signs), and rewrite it in a convenient form:
$$\frac{1}{2k}h'(t)=(-1)\cdot \frac{(1-t)^{k-1}+t^{k-1}}{2}+(k+1)\cdot \frac{(1-t)^k+t^k}{2}. \tag{1}$$
We can use the convexity/concavity of the functions $u^{k-1}$ and $u^k$ to obtain an upper bound for $h'(t)/(2k),$ and this upper bound turns out to be negative. First since $u^{k-1}$ is concave up, we have that the first fracion in $(1)$ (without the negative sign in front) is at least $(1/2)^{k-1}.$ Similarly since $u^k$ is concave down the second fraction in $(1)$ is at most $(1/2)^k.$  Putting these together we obtain the upper bound for $h'(t)/(2k)$ of
$$-(1/2)^{k-1}+(k+1)(1/2)^k=(1/2)^{k-1}(-1+(k+1)(1/2))
\\ =(1/2)^{k-1}(k-1)/2<0,$$
the last because of the assumption $0<k<1.$

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just can't figure out how to conclude that _Therefore the minimum of $w$ must occur on one of the three edges of the triangle $R$._

Comment: @Alex4814 It's a standard result that to minimize a differentiable function on a simple bounded region, such as a triangle together with its interior, which is compact, one first finds any critical points in the interior, and then those are possibilities, and also one must deal with the edges separately by other techniques (usually one variable ways). A critical point is where both partials are zero. In the above case there were none in the interior of the region, so...

Comment: Would it be OK to think that, given a certain $x_0$, $w(x_0,y_{upper}) < w(x_0,1/(k+1)) > w(x_0,y_{lower})$ also suggests the minimum be on the boundary?

Comment: @alex4814 I tried that approach, but found that it was difficult to keep track of whether $x,y$ were before or after $1/(k+1)$, which is the value at which the function $f(x)$ attains its max. It's clear e.g. that if $x<1/(k+1)$ and also $x+y<1$ then one can decrease $x$ a bit and keep $f(y)-f(x)$ positive. But the cases got too involved.